# My SwiftUI View doesn't update navigation title for third level

Tags: swift, swiftui, watchos

I have prepared a simple example with three levels:

```
struct Element: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let text: String
    init(text: String) {
        self.text = text
    }
}

struct FirstView: View {
    @State var elements = [Element(text: "a"), Element(text: "b")]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(elements) { element in
                NavigationLink {
                    SecondView()
                } label: {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 3, content: {
                        Text(element.text)
                            .font(.system(size: 12))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    })
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("First")
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    @State var elements = [Element(text: "1"), Element(text: "2")]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(elements) { element in
                NavigationLink {
                    ThirdView()
                } label: {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 3, content: {
                        Text(element.text)
                            .font(.system(size: 12))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    })
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Second")
        }
    }
}

struct ThirdView: View {
    @State var elements = [Element(text: "+"), Element(text: "-")]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(elements) { element in
                NavigationLink {
                    SecondView()
                } label: {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 3, content: {
                        Text(element.text)
                            .font(.system(size: 12))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    })
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Third")
        }
    }
}
```

And this is what happens in Apple Watch when I go to the next levels:

[image]
[image]
[image]

As you can see for third view,navigation title was not updated. Why?

Is there also something wrong with rendering? When I swipe down second list it ends up like:

[image]

Comment: Most apps only need 1 navigation view, tab views and sheets are exceptions. Links inside navigstion views should not have another one.

Comment: No, it is not true. Using Mail App, I can push to even 4th level there...

Comment: The “rendering” issue is because you have multiple navigation views where you only need one.

Comment: But I need three, not one... is it limited to only one?

Comment: You need 3 NavigationLinks but only 1 NavigationView at the top. Tab views are exceptions you need 1 navigation view on each tab in that case not above the tab view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove `NavigationView` from around the `SecondView` and `ThirdView`, i.e.

```
struct SecondView: View {
    @State var elements = [Element(text: "1"), Element(text: "2")]
    var body: some View {
        List(elements) { element in
            NavigationLink {
                ThirdView()
            } label: {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 3, content: {
                    Text(element.text)
                        .font(.system(size: 12))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                })
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Second")
    }
}
```

If you're building for watchOS 9.0+, you should probably use the new `NavigationStack`