# How to center VStack horizontally inside List with SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, watchos

I have a simple view:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List(months) { month in
            NavigationLink {
                MonthView(month: month)
            } label: {
                VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 8, content: {
                    Text("abc")
                    Text("abcdef")
                    Text("a")
                })
            }
            .listRowBackground(
                Color(uiColor: mode.darkUnderlayBackgroundColor)
                    .clipped()
                    .cornerRadius(10)
            )
        }
        .navigationTitle(months.first?.descriptiveYear ?? "")
    }
}
```

and result is:

[image]

How can I center it in a whole view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set the `maxWidth` to `infinity` using the `.frame` modifier. This will allow it to expand horizontally to take up as much room as it needs

```
VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 8) {
    Text("abc")
    Text("abcdef")
    Text("a")
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
```

Comment: Maybe you know the answer for that question also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75209340/2725435

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk Answered

Comment: Maybe do you know the answer for another question? ;) https://stackoverflow.com/q/75227399/2725435